# error with csvReader line when using OpenCsv

Tags: java, csv

I am getting an error with my code and I don't understand why. I am using OpenCsv library and trying to save my CSV into an array. The CSV has Columns that look like: Date, Sold, Code and then information under it like: 1123, may4, 0021;3323;

My code is:

```
 private static final String SAMPLE_CSV ="C:\\Users\\Documents\\o.csv\\";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


     { 

        try (
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV));
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
        ) {
            // Reading Records One by One in a String array
            String[] nextRecord;
            while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Order num : " + nextRecord[0]);
                System.out.println("SoldToAct : " + nextRecord[1]);
                System.out.println("RequestedDelivery : " + nextRecord[2]);
                System.out.println("BaseCode : " + nextRecord[3]);
                 System.out.println("Option Code : " + nextRecord[4]);
                System.out.println("==========================");
            }
        }
```

the error is in the CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader); line.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the double backslashes at the end of `SAMPLE_CSV`:

Change from:

```
private static final String SAMPLE_CSV ="C:\\Users\\Documents\\o.csv\\";
```

To this:

```
private static final String SAMPLE_CSV ="C:\\Users\\Documents\\o.csv";
```

Comment: It didnt work, Still get the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils error

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034653/2848676 resolve your java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ?

Comment: how would I download the apache commons lang